# Kong 0.10.x - JWT authentication get token access

Tags: kong

On Kong document: https://getkong.org/plugins/jwt/#create-a-jwt-credential

After that step, how to i can get  access token?

it's like: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhMzZjMzA0OWIzNjI0OWEzYzlmODg5MWNiMTI3MjQzYyIsImV4cCI6MTQ0MjQzMDA1NCwibmJmIjoxNDQyNDI2NDU0LCJpYXQiOjE0NDI0MjY0NTR9.AhumfY35GFLuEEjrOXiaADo7Ae6gt_8VLwX7qffhQN4

My issue:

- User request Kong server get a access_token
- Kong server result a access_token
- User use that access_token to verify authentication on hosts (ex: kong:8000/products), after verified successfully, Kong server will points upstream_url (ex: my.api.com/products)

Please help to clear that.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Using the values returned by the API you'll be able to create the token yourself. In order to help you with that, you can use an existing implementation like this one in Node.js https://github.com/jwtk/njwt